# Hash tag on URL gets stripped off upon clicking link on Windows Mail

Tags: url, windows-mail

In our newsletter we have a link with this URL:

`http://www.someshop.com/index.php?a=some_name#same_page_anchor`

This works in Gmail and Yahoo. However, in Windows Mail, when we click the link, the `#same_page_anchor` gets removed, hence, the user is not directed to the part of the page that we want to.

When we view the link on the email (hovering mouse on link), it does show the complete URL, only when it gets to the browser, the `#same_page_anchor` gets truncated.

Any idea why is this so?

Comment: I just answered a similar question on stackoverflow.com Not sure if you are using a framework like Laravel or Rails, but this may give you a solution. [Outlook strips URL hash from email](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20668680/2468674)

Answer (score 0):

This [seems](http://www.vistax64.com/live-mail/257044-anchors-pound-signs-truncated-email-links.html) to be a long-standing bug in the app.

If you're using **ID** anchors, maybe **Name** anchors will work better as mentioned [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3322/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/)?

**ID anchors** - `<a href="#anchorname">...</a>` → `<h2 id="anchorname">...</h2>`

**Name anchors** - `<a href="#anchorname">...</a>` → `<a name="anchorname">...</a>`